# Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without building a function in tf 2.0

Tags: reinforcement-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-probability

I want to build an asynchronous advantage actor-critic model (a3c) of an agent with multiple actions in tensorflow 2.0.  Some actions have continuous actions, on the other hand, others have discrete actions.

For these actions, I use tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag library in tensorflow-probability package. But I spent two days struggling this. But I don't know how to build a network to get the value of multiple actions.

I built a function to make distributions for multiple actions and I input logit tensor (output tensor of actor network) to this function below. The function will return distributions of each action.

```
def make_dist(space, logits):
        if space.is_continuous():
            mu, logstd = tf.split(logits, 2, axis=-1)
            return tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag(mu, tf.exp(logstd))
        else:
            return tfp.distributions.Categorical(logits)
```

For the first time, I tested the environment with one continuous action. When I call 'sample' function of this distribution, The error is like the following.

```
File "C:\Users\SDS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\distributions\distribution.py", line 848, in sample
    return self._call_sample_n(sample_shape, seed, name, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SDS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\distributions\transformed_distribution.py", line 373, in _call_sample_n
    x = self._sample_n(n, seed, **distribution_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SDS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\distributions\transformed_distribution.py", line 353, in _sample_n
    **distribution_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SDS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\distributions\distribution.py", line 848, in sample
    return self._call_sample_n(sample_shape, seed, name, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SDS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\distributions\distribution.py", line 826, in _call_sample_n
    samples = self._sample_n(n, seed, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SDS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\distributions\normal.py", line 185, in _sample_n
    axis=0)
  File "C:\Users\SDS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\dispatch.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SDS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 1431, in concat
    return gen_array_ops.concat_v2(values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\SDS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 1257, in concat_v2
    "ConcatV2", values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\SDS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 481, in _apply_op_helper
    value, as_ref=input_arg.is_ref)
  File "C:\Users\SDS-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 1264, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    raise RuntimeError("Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without "
RuntimeError: Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without building a function.
```

I used to use keras and pytorch. I am a newbie of tensorflow 2.0. As far as I know, the placeholder in tf 1.x was deprecated because of eager execution. The problem is related to that.